# Ad-hoc Testing is Not working on an iPod Touch but works on iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

I developed an app and I created a Provisioning profile and an .ipa file. I have tested with iPad and iPhone it works perfectly. But is fails to sync with iPod touch. Do anybody have experience with this?

Comment: Have all the devices the same iOS version?

Comment: My Deployment target is 5.0 . My iPhone is running on 5.0 and my iPad is running on 5.01 . My iPod Touch is 5.0.1

Comment: exactly what error you get while syncing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i answer to my own question. Go to `target --> Summary --> Check Enable Entitlements`

Answer (score 1):

This looks a problem that device is not added to your ad hoc provisioning profile
Please recheck your device added to your provisioning profile

Comment: Thats is not the solution. No issues with provisioning files